# How to change Google throttled calls to resolved promises

Tags: javascript, php, csv, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm trying to add lat and long data to address records in our db so we could provide a store locator like page. I've been using [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator) as a guide. I'm trying to create a csv file of geocoded addresses with ids to import to our db. I eventually want to automate this but for now I'm doing it manually for the initial upload.

We have over 3000 records in our db and I keep hitting the query limits with the geocoding api. I've added a delay for each request like suggested on multiple questions here. Unfortunately most of these answers are before Google changed the pricing structure and quota of their apis. It seems that after 1000 or so I keep getting the dreaded `API OVER QUERY LIMIT` error. Some calls work after I get the error but the longer I run the code, the success to error ratio drops.

Google documentation says the QPS for Geocoding is 50 but I've found issues when doing more than 10. So I added a delay of 1500 ms to space out my requests but it doesn't seem to work. Paying for a premium plan is not an option, since we only need to do this every 30 days, as per googles data retention policy. I'm doing this client-side since our server doesn't have java, node, pip, or go setup.

Edit: I've done some more searching and wrapped my geocoding into a function and if it fails, recursively call it again after a delay. But page keeps crashing once I get I start getting the over limit errors. What I don't understand is why it throws hundreds of these errors, more so than the number of addresses to parse, if I'm returning the failed calls in a `setTimeout` function.

Edit2: Ok I'm getting closer. I made my geocoding function return a promise and declared it outside of the main code. Wrapping `setTimeout` over the section that goecodes spaced them out appropriately. I set a catch to deal with the error and retry. Now my problem is that my `Promise.all()` is resolving even if some of the promises failed and are still in the middle of retrying. I don't want it to complete until failed promises are resolved.

My code is as follows:

db.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "table");
$addresses = array();

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$query = "SELECT
    id,
    Concat(
        primary_address_street, ' ', primary_address_city,
        ' ', primary_address_state, ' ',
        primary_address_postalcode
    ) as address
FROM
    `nurses`
WHERE
    primary_address_postalcode <> ''
    AND primary_address_street <> ''
    AND primary_address_city <> ''
    AND primary_address_state <> ''
    AND first_name <> ''
    AND last_name <> ''
    ";

$i = 0;
//Used multi_query because I originally did multiple queries
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                $addresses[$i] = array('id' => $row[0], 'address' => $row[1]);
                $i++;
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

echo json_encode($addresses);
```

map.js

```
var map;
var nurses = [];

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: myLat, lng: myLng },
        zoom: 15,
        // disableDefaultUI: true,
        // gestureHandling: 'none',
        // zoomControl: false
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function() {
        // console.log(this.responseText);
        var dbAdresses = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        // console.log(dbAdresses);

        var locationPromises = [];
        dbAdresses.forEach(function(e, i) {
            locationPromises.push(geocodeAddress(e, i));
        });

        Promise.all(locationPromises)
            .then(function(locationsFound) {
                // console.log(locationsFound);
                // console.log(nurses);
                const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value;
                const header = Object.keys(nurses[0]);
                let csv = nurses.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
                csv.unshift(header.join(','));
                csv = csv.join('\r\n');

                //Download the file as CSV
                var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv]);
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                downloadLink.href = url;
                downloadLink.download = "nurses-addresses.csv";
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
            })
            .catch(function(e) { console.log(e); });
    };
    oReq.open("get", "db_csv.php", true);
    oReq.send();
}

function geocodeAddress(entry, index) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': JSON.stringify(entry.address)
                }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(results);
                        var person = {
                            'id': entry.id,
                            'lat': results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                            'lng': results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                        };
                        nurses.push(person);
                        resolve(results);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        reject(status);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000 * index);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log(entry.id + " failed retrying in 5 seconds");
            setTimeout(function() {
                geocodeAddress(entry, index);
            }, 5000);
        });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your QPS to higher value? It is under the [Capping Usage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage), you might also be reaching the maximum request per day that's why it's giving you an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.

Comment: @ShawnDomingo So I checked that page and 2 graphs are for premium plans and the last one says I have 5000 per 100 seconds, which is no where near what I'm getting. I'm getting throttled after making around 200 per 100 seconds. Still I prefer just redoing the promises in my code but the way it is now, the `Promise.all()` isn't waiting for my delayed retries to finish before generating a csv.

Comment: After further investigation, I found out that you are exceeding the API's rate limit since you are geocoding by batch, This API is not intended to be used for batch processing of data but rather to react upon user interaction. For batch processing or bulk requests, I recommend to use [Geocoding API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) instead.

Comment: I guess that makes more sense. It doesn't mention a php implementation. Would it just be a curl request?

Comment: Yes, it would be Curl request in this case.